# Creating windows service without using timer control

Tags: c#, .net, windows-services

I am creating windows service, whatever the article I am going through they are using `System.Timers.Timer`, without mentioning that why they are using it.

Is it mandatory to use `Timer`?

These below urls are using `Timer` with windows service

https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/8a67c0/create-and-install-windows-service-step-by-step-in-C-Sharp/

https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/create-windows-services-in-c-sharp/

https://dzone.com/articles/create-windows-services-in-c

https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Tutorial-to-create-a-simple-Windows-Service-with-sample-example-in-C-and-VBNet.aspx

Can't it be done just by writing code in these methods

```
protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
{
    base.OnStart(args);
    GetFailedProductDetails();
}

protected override void OnStop()
{
    base.OnStop();
}
```

**Edit:**

Logic to execute service every 30 mins

```
<appSettings>
<add key ="Mode" value ="Interval"/>
<add key ="IntervalMinutes" value ="30"/>
<add key="ClientSettingsProvider.ServiceUri" value="" />
</appSettings>
```

My goal:

I want to run this service every 30 mins to execute `GetFailedProductDetails()` method. For that I have written code in `App.config` file.

Comment: What does the service do after `GetFailedProductDetails()`? Shouldn't it repeat its job?

Comment: when your business case does not ask for a timer, then don't use one. many services wait for external signals, or use a FileSystemWatcher, or something else to trigger doing whatever they do. describe your task at hand, and the problems you encounter. Anything better than an endless loop does the trick - the goal is to have ~0 CPU usage when the service is idle, and a timer is one possible construct to achieve this.

Comment: @oerkelens - I want to repeat t every hour but that code we have to write in in `App.config` file. please check updated question.

Comment: @CeeMcSharpface - I want to execute GetFailedProductDetails() method every 30 mins as written in app.confi file. Is this not the complete code to do so? I am thinking this service will start always every 30 mins but when I see timers in few articles I got confused.

Comment: `OnStart` will be called when the service receives a start command from the OS (the service control manager), when it is not already running or if paused, once. "every <configurable> minutes" is definitely a valid use case for a timer. just take care to address the case when a single instance of the process could take longer than the interval, so as not to exhaust ressources (queue or defer)

Comment: well - services are used to listen for incoming connections (usually). Service can handle repeatable tasks using the Timer but you may check the [Windows Task scheduler](https://www.windowscentral.com/how-create-automated-task-using-task-scheduler-windows-10) - it can be configured to run any application. And it is pretty good in scheduling. So you can write ordinary app (console) and schedule it using the system. But you have to call the `GetFailedProductDetails` in windows service periodically with timer. `OnStart` is executed only once, when service starts.

Comment: @ArvindChourasiya Settings are not "logic". `App.config` does not contain "code". The `<appSettings>` thing is not an existing automatic feature. The example you copied that from goes on to explain you need to explicitly read those values from the config and use them to set up a timer object that actually starts the service operations. Starting the service is not the same thing as repeating a task; the service only gets started _once_ and then just keeps running.

Comment: I would advise employing https://www.quartz-scheduler.net/ which uses CRON format (https://www.freeformatter.com/cron-expression-generator-quartz.html) for scheduling the tasks. When your requirements change and you have multiple tasks to schedule, you will be grateful for "doing it right at the first time" :)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is based on assumptions made after only half-reading a bunch of guides on the subject. OP copied a piece of xml config from a guide and assumed that that would automagically create a scheduler for him.

Comment: @Nyerguds - Instead of voting to close or commenting you can answer my questions like where I am wrong what should I do(As u said already). Thanks

Comment: You want an answer? Fine. I'll post it as answer then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A service does not repeat. It simply starts once, and then runs as long as it is not stopped. If it needs to do repeated tasks, you need to take care of the repeating yourself, in your code.

Of course, you *could* set up an ugly system with an endless `for`-loop and a `Thread.Sleep()`, but the issue there is, when starting a service, Windows expects the `OnStart` to *finish*, so it can conclude that the service is **started**, rather than **still starting up**. The `OnStart` function should *prepare* everything to make the service operations run, but it should not execute these operations itself.

So, the reason the timer is used for that is so the `OnStart` function can finish correctly, and then after that, periodically, the service operations, in your case the `GetFailedProductDetails()` function, can be started by the timer.

---

As for that piece of config, as I said in my comment, a bit of xml is not code. The guide you copied that from has explicitly written programming to read, interpret and apply these settings, to set up a Timer object to make it repeat in the configured intervals. Copying that xml without copying the accompanying code will do nothing to help you.

You *can* use the config file to set up the interval settings, of course, but then you'll also have to actually write the code to read them. The concept of a repeating service doesn't *need* such settings, though. You can perfectly program the service with a hardcoded half-hour interval and leave it at that.